# Try to serve static index.html with NGINX giving 404 error

Tags: nginx, nginx-location, nginx-ingress

My NGINX conf file looks like this:

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
    server_name  site.com;
    root         /root/mysite;


    resolver 8.8.8.8;

        location / {
            try_files $uri /index.html =404;
        }

        error_page 404 /404.html;
            location = /40x.html {
        }

        error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
            location = /50x.html {
        }

}
```

This configuration gives me 404 error. But why? This directive `try_files $uri /index.html =404;` should try file and if not exist fallback to 404 error.

But I do have a file in root directory.

Comment: Is there anything in the nginx error log? Are the permissions on the root directory adequate?

Comment: nothing, last error in log 10 hours ago

Comment: `try_files` may mask error log entries, try removing the `try_files` statement, and see if an error log entry appears. Use `nginx -T` (uppercase `T`) to ensure that the configuration above is being read by Nginx. Also, this is a secure server and missing some mandatory statements, are they inherited from the outer block or did you remove them for brevity?